# knockout mvvm binding with metro.js datepicker

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, datepicker, ko-custom-binding, metro.js

I was trying to hack my way around with the metro.js datepicker and knockout. So far my datepicker binding code looks like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
  init: function(el, va, ba, model, ctx) {
    var prop = va();
    $(el).datepicker({
      onSelect: function(txt, date) {
        prop(date);
      }
    });
  },
  update: function(el, va, ba, model, ctx) {
    var prop = va();
    var date = ko.unwrap(prop);

    if(date) {
      applyDate(date);
    }

    function applyDate(dt) {
      var j = $(el);
      var dp = j.data('datepicker');
      var inp = j.find('input');
      var fmt = dp.options.format;
      var sDate = format(fmt, dt);
      // dp._calendar.calendar.dayClick(sDate, dt);
      // inp.value = sDate;
      dp._calendar.calendar('setDate', sDate);
      j.find('input').val(dp._calendar.calendar('getDate')).trigger('change', sDate);
    }

    function format(fmt, dt) {
      fmt = fmt.replace('yyyy', dt.getFullYear());
      fmt = fmt.replace('mm', pad(dt.getMonth() + 1));
      fmt = fmt.replace('dd', pad(dt.getDate()));
      return fmt;
    }

    function pad(n) {
      return parseInt(n) < 10 ? '0' + n: '' + n;
    };
  }
}
```

Issue is that when I issue a model update on the `date` property its bound to the datepicker doesn't update. I mean, it does it the very first time, but post that, it fails to update the textbox; calendar shows okay however. Ultimately I need to change the logic in the `applyDate` function...

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/rupaqolexa/1/edit?html,js,output

Update: Another issue just cropped up...it doesn't work in IE 10+. The date appears as `NaN` in the UI...

Update: Steps for reproduction

1. type date 2nd text box: 2013/05/13 & click on the Change button. Observe date is updated in the datepicker textbox. This works as expected. (Except in IE).
2. type another date in the textbox & click the change button. Observe the date is not updated in the datepicker textbox. Expected here that the datepicker textbox updates with latest value.

Comment: Please, try to explain the problem with other words. It's unfortunate that the problem can't be understood even with a working jsbin sample. BTW, you should start using SO code snippets: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @JotaBe updated post with reproduction steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `update` part of your custom binding you need to make all the changes to the bound elements, which include the calendar widget, and the related `input` element.

I've modified the code to do so, so that it now works.

```js
function ViewModel(date) {
  var model = this;
  model.date = ko.observable(date);
  model.set = function() {
    var val = $('#somedate').val();
    var dt = new Date(val);
    model.date(dt);
  };
}

ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
  init: function(el, va, ba, model, ctx) {
    var prop = va();
    $(el).datepicker({
      onSelect: function(txt, date) {
        prop(date);
      }
    });
  },
  update: function(el, va, ba, model, ctx) {
    var newDate = ko.unwrap(va());

    if(newDate) {
      var $el = $(el);
      var datePicker = $el.data('datepicker');
      var $input = $el.find('input');
      var formattedDate = format(datePicker.options.format, newDate);
      datePicker._calendar.calendar('setDate', formattedDate);
      $input.val(formattedDate);
      //$input.val(dp._calendar.calendar('getDate'))
      //  .trigger('change', sDate);
    }

    function format(fmt, dt) {
      fmt = fmt.replace('yyyy', dt.getFullYear());
      fmt = fmt.replace('mm', pad(dt.getMonth() + 1));
      fmt = fmt.replace('dd', pad(dt.getDate()));
      return fmt;
    }

    function pad(n) {
      return parseInt(n) < 10 ? '0' + n: '' + n;
    }
  }
};

var m = new ViewModel();

$(function(){
  ko.applyBindings(m);
});
```

```html
<link href="//metroui.org.ua/css/metro.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//metroui.org.ua/css/metro-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//metroui.org.ua/css/metro-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://metroui.org.ua/css/metro-schemes.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://metroui.org.ua/js/metro.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="input-control text" data-bind="datepicker: date">
    <input type="text">
    <button class="button"><span class="mif-calendar"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Date</label>
  <div class="input-control text">
    <input type="text" id="somedate"/>
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Change" data-bind="click: set"/>
</div>

<div>
  <code data-bind="text: date"></code>
</div>
```

However there is still a little hiccup: the datepiceker's calendar `setdate` adss new selected date, instead of replacing selected ones. Please, see the API docs to solve this yourself.

Comment: there is an issue on IE. The calendar is completely flawed if you change the date in the model.

Comment: I think you should create a new question for that problem, so it can be treated individually. You don't need to change the date from the model: do change it useing the calendar widget, and it also fails. Try to isolate the problem checking if it's a problem with the binding or the widget. Thank you.